# Visualization of sensor output in RViz

Tags: ros, rviz, urdf

I'm trying to visualize the output of a ultrasone sensor (HC-SR04) in RViz with ROS1. When I do a `rostopic echo /RightSonarDistance` I receive the values on the terminal.

[image: terminal output here]

So this seems to work.

I have created a XACRO file which loads into RViz correctly but when I add a Range topic and select a sensor I get the message that the "Frame does not exist".

[image: RViz output]

I assume there is an error in my XACRO file but I'm not 100% sure about that but to be sure here is my XACRO file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="r2g2">

<!-- Define the material for visualization -->
<material name="gray">
  <color rgba="0.5 0.5 0.5 1"/>
</material>

<!-- Define the wheel radius and separation distance -->
<xacro:property name="base_width" value="0.17"/>
<xacro:property name="base_len" value="0.27"/>
<xacro:property name="wheel_radius" value="0.035"/>
<xacro:property name="base_wheel_gap" value="0.007"/>
<xacro:property name="wheel_separation" value="0.17"/>
<xacro:property name="wheel_joint_offset" value="0.045"/>

<!--Base Footprint-->
<link name="base_footprint">
  <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
          <box size="0.001 0.001 0.001" />
      </geometry>
  </visual>
</link>

<!-- Base Link -->
<link name="base_link">
  <visual>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <box size="${base_len} ${base_width} 0.01"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="gray"/>
  </visual>
</link>

  <!--base_link to base_footprint Joint-->
<joint name="base_link_joint" type="fixed">
  <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
  <parent link="base_footprint"/>
  <child link="base_link" />
</joint>
  
<!-- Left Wheel and Link-->
<link name="left_wheel_link">
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="0.009"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="gray"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="0.009"/>
      </geometry>
  </collision>       
</link>

<joint name="left_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="left_wheel_link"/>
    <origin xyz="${wheel_joint_offset} ${((base_width/2)+base_wheel_gap)*1} -0.005" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

  <!-- Right Wheel and Link-->
<link name="right_wheel_link">
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="0.009"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="gray"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="0.009"/>
      </geometry>
  </collision>   
</link>

<joint name="right_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="right_wheel_link"/>
    <origin xyz="${wheel_joint_offset} ${((base_width/2)+base_wheel_gap)*-1} -0.005" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

<!-- Right Ultrasone sensor-->
<joint name="right_ultrasone_joint" type="fixed">
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="right_ultrasone_link"/>
    <origin xyz="${(base_len/2)} ${(base_width/2)*-1} -0.01" rpy="0 0 0.523598"/>
</joint>

<link name="right_ultrasone_link">
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="0.005" length="0.015"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="gray"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="0.005" length="0.015"/>
      </geometry>
  </collision> 
</link>
```

I also did a `rosrun tf view_frames` which gave me the following information:

[image]

Can someone help me out to make the output visibile on RViz? I would really appreciate, at the moment I don't know where to look for the error.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue by myself.

I did not refer to the correct frame names. In my publisher code I I referred to a different frame as used in the XACRO code.

My publisher code:

[image]

My XACRO code:
[image]

These names need to be identical.

So this issue is solved. New problem arrose that the angle of the sensor beam is wrong LOL but that's another issue